# How to display the ajax response inside sumo select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3, sumoselect.js

I am using sumoselect (http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/sumoselect_demo.html).

I have three dropdowns called as `countries, state, and cities`. Countries are displaying in the dropdown and `onchange` depending upon the countries id state name will display in the dropdown.

Now my issue is, I am not getting the state name in the dropdown but getting on view source. Check below image. If I remove sum select class from the dropdown then it's working.

[image]
[image]

**JS**

```
$('.search_sumo').SumoSelect({search: true, searchText: 'Enter here.'});

$(".country_change").on('change',function(){
      var country_id=$(this).val();
      var select_list = $(this).data('target'); // The dropdown ID
  $.ajax({
      url:baseUrl +"/System_control/statename",
      method:"POST",
      data:"country_id="+country_id,
      dataType: "json",
      success:function(data){
        //alert(data);
        $('#'+select_list).empty();
        var placeholder="<option value='' disabled selected>Select state</option>";
        $('#'+select_list).html(placeholder);
            $.each(data, function(i, data) {
          $('#'+select_list).append("<option value='" + data.id + "'>" + data.state_name + "</option>");
            });
      }
     });
  });
```

**HTML**

```
 <select name="country" class="form-control search_sumo country_change" data-target="target_state_dropdown">
     <option selected disabled=""> Select country</option>
     <?php foreach ($get_country as $row) {?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" <?php echo set_select('country',$row->id,False);?>><?php echo $row->country_name;?></option>
      <?php }?>
   </select>

 <select name="state" class="form-control search_sumo state_get" id="target_state_dropdown" data-target="city_dropdown">
 <option selected disabled=""> Select state</option>
 </select>
```

Can any one help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@questionbank

You need to reload the sumo init for asynchronously loaded select box in your success action.

So in your Ajax success should be as follows..

```
success:function(data){

    $('#'+select_list).empty();
    var placeholder="<option value='' disabled selected>Select state</option>";
    $('#'+select_list).html(placeholder);
    $.each(data, function(i, data) {
        $('#'+select_list).append("<option value='" + data.id + "'>" + data.state_name + "</option>");
    });
    $('.search_sumo')[1].sumo.reload();
}
```

Comment: Give me some time to check your answer

Comment: I just want to know why you use [1]?

Comment: @questionbank you are using class selector[$('.search_sumo')]..It always returns array of elements..with index starts from 0.So 1st index is your ajax loaded select element.It's working..right?

Comment: Yes, It's working perfectly.    I have to use   $('.search_sumo')[2].sumo.reload();  for the city dropdown. correct?

Comment: Yeah..whenever dropdowns are loaded dynamically...you nee to load it to make it effect on 'SumoSelect' effect..